# Telerik Controls Not working on IIS 7.5

Tags: telerik, iis-7.5

I am developing a telerik Asp.net Ajax project using .net 4.5 and vs 2012. My development environment is working great however when I deploy my app on IIS 7.5 my default.aspx screen that contains 3 radcomboboxes and a radgrid is not working at all. When I say its not working the comboboxes are not dropping down and the radgrid controls are not responding. However when I replace one of the comboboxes with a Microsoft Dropdown I get the expected control behavior. I'am not sure what is causing this.Any ideas or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

These are my handlers in web.config.

```
 <handlers>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
  <add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=6.1.12.823, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 2):

WebResource.axd file which contains all the resources pertaining to Telerik is not getting loaded on runtime. That's the reason you see an unexpected behavior. Make sure that following httphandler exist in your web config file.

`<add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>`

Refer to the following link for more help.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-web-resources-troubleshooting.html

I would also advice that if you are not using authentication in your app and if there are lines related to it exist in your web config, get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this by removing the property UpdatePanelsRenderMode = "Inline" from inside my RadAjaxManager. This property if is set to inline places the contents inside html spans and for some reason the WS did not like it.